# mouseclick change the color of text and unbind the previously clicked

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to achieve something like what we see in the gmail. When I hover over it changes the text color and on click changes the color of the text to red. When I click on the other row the same thing happens. However, in my case I am missing something because of my novice knowledge. I need to unbind the previous click because the previous click keeps the text red.

```
$("#index td").hover(
            function() {
                $(this).css( {'background': '#e9e7e7',
                              'cursor': 'pointer'});
            },
            function () {
                $(this).css({'background': '#ffffff',
                              'cursor': 'pointer'});
            }
        ).click(function(){
            $(this).css({ 'color': 'red'});
        });
```

**EDIT**

```
<tr style="background-image: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); cursor: pointer; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial; " class="selected"><td style="padding:2.5px 0px 2.5px 2px;">XYZZZZ</td></tr>
```

Comment: When you say "previously clicked" do you mean the element that you clicked before this one?

Comment: I don't think that you mean "unbind". I think you mean that you just want to remove the styling that was applied to the previously selected item. If you "unbind" then you wouldn't be able to reselect the item. See my example below.

Comment: Yes, I mean to remove the styling for the previously selected item.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, then you want to reset the red color that was previously set on the clicked row.

If so then inside the click you need to set the color of all the other to default,

```
    var $tds = $("#index td");
    //..
    //..
    .click(function(){
        $tds.css({'background': '#ffffff',
                          'cursor': 'pointer'});

        $(this).css({ 'color': 'red'});
    });
```

Alternatively the proper way is to have 2 css class defined 1. highlight 2. selected and then add/remove them accordingly.

**CSS:**

```
.highlight { background: '#ffffff', cursor: 'pointer'}
.selected { color: 'red'; }
```

**JS:**

```
    var $tds = $("#index td");

    $tds.hover(
        function() {
            $(this).addClass('highlight');
        }, function () {
            $(this).removeClass('highlight');
        }
    ).click(function(){
        $tds.removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
```

Note: If I am not mistaken such things are usually applied on `tr`s and not `td`s

Comment: For some reason the neither addClass nor removeClass is applying the styles.

Comment: @user525146 Do you have jQuery included? Also check for any script errors.

Comment: Yes, I have jquery included and it is working for the other styles etc., Its applying the css and not the js addClass or removeClass and there are no script errors

Answer (score 1):

I think you are better off handling the hover event with CSS and the click with JS. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZmcNN/1/

Comment: For some reason the js doesn't apply the style with the click event. My function is in the $(document).ready(function(){});

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that you could verify that your selector that you are binding on matches the elements you are trying to target.

Comment: Some inline style is overriding the applied class style. I edited my question what I see in the chrome console

Comment: I still have the question, its not working though style class is seen in the console. In the styles tab the red color is striked out meaning its overridden..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I fully understand the question, but I think you might want [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function:

```
$("#foo").one("click", function(){
    alert("This will be displayed only once.");
});
```

The above is basically equivalent to doing this:

```
$("#foo").bind("click", function(e) {
    alert("This will be displayed only once.");
    $(this).unbind(e);
});
```